# Prolog - Append head to new list for every recursive run?

Tags: prolog

Hiyya,

I'm currently working on a type of "virtual shop" in Prolog, and I'm trying to work on the functionality to update an aisle. However, seeing my rather limited knowledge of Prolog, I'm facing some difficulties.

The predicate(s) and call:

```cpp
/*  % First parameter: The shop (or "old list") that contains the unmodified data
    % Second parameter: Simply a index/counter keeping track of where we are in 
        the "recursive loop"
    % Third parameter: Index of where we want to get. We keep recursively looping 
        and either incrementing or decrementing until the second and third 
        parameters are the same.
    % Fourth parameter: Since the first parameter is a list of lists, this 
        parameter will contain the "inner list" which will replace another inner 
        list.
    % Fifth parameter: The shop (or "new list"), the result, whatever you'd like 
        to call it 
    */
update_aisle( [H|T], CurrentAisle, TargetAisle, NewObj, NewShop):-
    CurrentAisle < TargetAisle,
    Temp is CurrentAisle + 1,
    append( NewShop, H),
    update_aisle( T, Temp, TargetAisle, NewObj, NewShop).
update_aisle( [H|T], CurrentAisle, TargetAisle, NewObj, NewShop):-
    CurrentAisle > TargetAisle,
    Temp is CurrentAisle - 1,
    append( NewShop, H),
    update_aisle( T, Temp, TargetAisle, NewObj, NewShop).
update_aisle( [H|T], CurrentAisle, TargetAisle, NewObj, NewShop):-
    CurrentAisle is TargetAisle,
    nth0( 0, T, TempT),
    append( NewObj, TempT, NewShop).

?- Shop = [ [ "Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies" ], 
            [ "Beer", "Cider", "Juice" ],
            [ "Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage" ] ],
   write(Shop), nl,
   update_aisle(Shop, 0, 1, ["Beer", "Milk", "Juice"], NewShop),
   write(NewShop), nl.
```

Right now, I'm only getting directive (failed), so not getting very far at all (and I'm going to assume that's because `append/2` is not cooperating as I'd want it to). However, what I'd want to achieve is this:

```cpp
Shop = [ [ "Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies" ], 
         [ "Beer", "Cider", "Juice" ],
         [ "Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage" ] ].

NewShop = [ [ "Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies" ], 
            [ "Beer", "Milk", "Juice" ], 
            [ "Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage" ] ].
```

So in other words, I'm trying to loop through the list, and append the "head" of the list for each recursive loop for as long as we're not where we want to be in the list. Once we've reached that point, we're mostly out after appending `NewObj` to the list (instead of the head, as that is the one being replaced) and job done.

I feel like I'm missing something glaringly obvious, but any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`append/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) is definitely not correclty used. Wherever it appears, it will make `H` the result of merging the sublists of `NewShop`. That's not what is wanted. Also, ` CurrentAisle is TargetAisle` is wrong. [`is/2`] is arithmetic evaluation of the right-hand-side. You want to check for equality, right? Then `=` ("make sure left and right unify") or `=:=` (make sure arithmetic expressions on the left and right rfesolve the same)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Absolutely not trying to say you'd be wrong, but I just feel like that contradicts their documentation, that says `append/2` is `append(+ListOfLists, ?List)`? Unless their documentation does not keep orders in mind?

Comment: Try on the REPL: _forwards_: `append( [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] ,X).` gives `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].` _backwards_: `bagof([A,B], append( [A,B] , [1,2] ), S).` gives `S = [[[], [1, 2]], [[1], [2]], [[1, 2], []]].`

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Hm, okay! Does not seem to have resolved the issue simply by giving the arguments in the right order though, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you explain in simple words what `update_aisle` is supposed to do? What's its purpose? It's not clear to me why it needs all of those arguments. I know what each one means individually based upon their names, but why you need them or want them is unclear.

Comment: @lurker I can, but I feel like there'll be quite a bit to explain if we're to go into more detail than what was brought up from the question itself. Want to start a chat?

Comment: I'm only looking for information that anyone who might help would need to know. Your example of what you want the predicate to do is unclear to me. It has current aisle and target aisle parameters, for example. I'm not sure what these mean. You show an example of 0 and 1 for these, an input list of aisles, a new aisle, and a desired output list. It looks like your desired result is to just replace the target aisle of the input list with the new aisle. So I'm not sure why you then need the current aisle argument. There's probably more to it than that, which is why it needs explaining.

Comment: @lurker I can't argue with you about it because you're not wrong either. Will update the original question with that information ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to replace an item at a given index, in a list:

```erlang
% replace_at( In, At, With, Replaced )
replace_at( [],  _I, _N, []).
replace_at( [_|T], I, N, [N|T]) :- I =:= 0.
replace_at( [H|T], I, N, [H|T2]) :- I > 0, I2 is I-1,
   replace_at( T, I2, N,    T2).
```

Testing:

```erlang
?- Shop = [["Bread","Donuts","Cookies"],["Beer","Cider","Juice"],["Ham","Raw Meat","Sausage"]], 
   replace_at( Shop, 1,    ["Beer", "Milk", "Juice"],    NewShop), nl, 
   maplist( writeln, Shop), nl, maplist( writeln, NewShop), nl.

[Bread,Donuts,Cookies] 
[Beer,Cider,Juice]
[Ham,Raw Meat,Sausage]

[Bread,Donuts,Cookies]
[Beer,Milk,Juice]
[Ham,Raw Meat,Sausage]

Shop = [["Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies"], ["Beer", "Cider", "Juice"], ["Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage"]],
NewShop = [["Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies"], ["Beer", "Milk", "Juice"], ["Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage"]] ;
false.
```

Gives the output that you wanted.

That the elements of the list are themselves lists is immaterial here.

If on the other hand you shall ever want *two* indices to be used in the call, to specify that the `J`th element in the `I`th list (0-based) in a list of lists be replaced, you can just use the above predicate, twice, to accomplish that:

```erlang
% replace_at2d( In, AtLine, AtWord, With, Replaced )
replace_at2d(  LL,    I, J, W,     LL2 ) :-
  nth0(   I,   LL, L),                         % I-th line
  replace_at(      L,    J, W, L2 ),           % J-th word
  replace_at(  LL,    I,       L2, LL2 ).
```

Testing:

```erlang
?- Shop = [["Bread","Donuts","Cookies"],["Beer","Cider","Juice"],["Ham","Raw Meat","Sausage"]], 
   replace_at2d( Shop, 1, 1,    "Milk",    NewShop), nl, 
   maplist( writeln, Shop), nl, maplist( writeln, NewShop), nl.

[Bread,Donuts,Cookies]
[Beer,Cider,Juice]
[Ham,Raw Meat,Sausage]

[Bread,Donuts,Cookies]
[Beer,Milk,Juice]
[Ham,Raw Meat,Sausage]

Shop = [["Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies"], ["Beer", "Cider", "Juice"], ["Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage"]],
NewShop = [["Bread", "Donuts", "Cookies"], ["Beer", "Milk", "Juice"], ["Ham", "Raw Meat", "Sausage"]] ;
false.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: you're very welcome! adjust to the Prolog mindset, and it's all become *easy peasy*. :) ... specifically, Prolog is master *top-down* builder (of lists and other things). see [tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons] for more on that.